# Асинхронность: если выполняется длительный запрос, весь сервер висит у остальных пользователей

Tags: celery, django

Здравствуйте. Изучаю джанго, все устраивает пока дело не доходит до обработки длительных запросов (связка nginx-uwsgi-django). Получается если пользователь выполняет длительный запрос (происходит вычисление), весь сервер висит у остальных пользователей. Не могу понять как правильно организовать настройку сервера, на что обращать внимания (потоки, процессы). Единственный ли выход (без извращений) использовать celery везде на длительных запросах. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Сколько процессорных ядер у сервера? Во сколько потоков работает uwsgi? Если одно ядро или один поток - логично, что мощные вычисления будут его блокировать.

Comment: Один процессор, вычисления происходят на другом сервере БД. Как правильно настроить обработку таких ситуаций.

Comment: Нуже ребята, это стандартная вещь. Какие настройки надо провести в uwsgi либо что-то еще ? Как вы решаете эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

В питоне нет нормальной многопоточности. И джанго использует блокирующий IO. Так что да, штуки типа celery или очередей сообщений (их celery и использует) - единственный вариант. 
Максимум, что можно улучшить - запустить uwsgi в нескольких экземплярах, в зависимости от количества ядер (в оф. доках есть рецепты).